# why won't jquery datatable populate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

This is driving me nuts.  I have a web site that works fine.  Datatable populates from a .php ajax call.  I'm migrating that code to a different web site.  Identical ajax call but this time won't populate!

Here is the js of the one that works:

```
$('#divTable').DataTable({
    "ajax": "screen_highYield.php",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Symbol" },
        { "data": "CompanyName" },
        { "data": "ExDivDate" },
        { "data": "Dividend" },
        { "data": "DivYield" },
        { "data": "DivFrequency" },
        { "data": "DivPayDate" }
    ]    
});
```

And the html:

```
<div id="highYieldDiv">
<table id="divTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Symbol</th>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Ex-Div<br>Date</th>
            <th>Dividend</th>
            <th>Div<br>Yield%</th>
            <th>Div<br>Frequency</th>
            <th>Pay Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
</div>
```

Here is the js of the one that fails:

```
$('#divTable').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        url: "screen_highYield.php",
        "done": function() {
            alert('done');
        },
        "success": function(data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        "error": function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error');
        },
        "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
            alert( 'DataTables has finished its initialisation.' );
        }
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Symbol" },
        { "data": "CompanyName" },
        { "data": "ExDivDate" },
        { "data": "Dividend" },
        { "data": "DivYield" },
        { "data": "DivFrequency" },
        { "data": "DivPayDate" }
    ]    
});
```

And the html:

```
    <div id="highYieldDiv">
    <table id="divTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Symbol</th>
                <th>Company Name</th>
                <th>Ex-Div<br>Date</th>
                <th>Dividend</th>
                <th>Div<br>Yield%</th>
                <th>Div<br>Frequency</th>
                <th>Pay Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    </div>
```

I added the "done", "success", "error", and "initComplete" in an attempt to figure out what's wrong.  Nothing was output to the console.  Then I moved the js to the $(document).ready function and then I got the "success" to trigger.  (Didn't have to do that in the one that works.)  I took the json it output and verified it was valid json using jsonlint.  The table just says Loading...

I don't understand why it works one place an not another.  These black boxes are so mysterious and difficult to debug.  Ideas?

Comment: "*These black boxes are so mysterious and difficult to debug*", Yes - especially if you refuse to read documentation!! **1)** [success - Must not be overridden as it is used internally in DataTables](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) **2)** you have a malformed options section, `initComplete` is not part of the `ajax` struct.

Comment: As I said, it didn't work before I added those.  They were a debugging step.

Comment: Yes, you can use `ajax.dataSrc = function(d) {...}` for debugging purposes or post processing. You can use `ajax.error` as you are used to. You can also hook into the` xhr.dt` and `preXhr.dt` events.

Comment: What type of datatype are you returning ? Maybe is refusing to accept ? What is the response (null, empty, something else) if you remove the part of the table in the ajax call ?